# Data memory and Instructions on PIC18F4321

Tags: memory, microcontroller, pic

We are studying the PIC18F4321, and at some point my professor drew the following diagram on the board:

[image: data memory]

He made it look like instructions (such as ADDLW 0X02, MOVWF 0X24, etc) will take two addresses in data memory, because memory addresses in the PIC18F4321 only take a byte and instructions are 16 bits wide.

But in the datasheet of the PIC18F4321, I cannot find where it says that these 16 bits instructions will ever be stored in data memory. Before he said that, I had in mind that the data memory was for storing register values, not full instructions. On the other hand, I know that there is also program memory, but program memory it is not 8 bits wide, which makes his drawing even more confusing.

1) Are 16 bits instructions ever stored in Data Memory?

2) One way I found of trying to explain the picture is that perhaps the memory in question is not necessarily 8 bits wide, it is just that every address can only take 8 bits. So <8> would be simply stating how many bits you can hold in that address. Would this be a reasonable explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Are 16 bits instructions ever stored in Data Memory?

No. Data memory is not used for storing instructions - you cannot execute any code from data memory. All instructions are stored in program memory, which consists of 16 bit instruction words. The datasheet details the format and layout of the different instructions. Some instructions are single word, some require multiple words. The program memory is addressed by a 21 bit program counter, which encompasses a 2Mbyte space although for the PIC18F4321 there is just 8Kbytes of program memory, which equates to 4096 single-word instructions.

Data memory consists of 8 bit bytes, addressed by a 12 bit bus, which allows up to 4096 bytes of data memory although the PIC18F4321 has just 512 bytes of data memory, split into two banks of 256 bytes. This data memory contains the SFR's (special function registers) and the general purpose registers (GPR) that you use in your application.

All of this is explained in greater detail [in the datasheet for this device](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39689b.pdf), specifically in Section 5.

The way that program memory is addressed by the program counter (PC) enforces the 16-bit instruction word alignment by forcing the least significant bit of the PC to zero, which forces access in multiples of two bytes. Quoting from the datasheet:

> The PC addresses bytes in the program memory. To prevent the PC from
>   becoming misaligned with word instructions, the Least Significant bit
>   of PCL is fixed to a value of ‘0’. The PC increments by 2 to address
>   sequential instructions in the program memory.

I suggest that you thoroughly read Section 5 of the linked datasheet and see if you have any remaining doubts. It contains a lot of detail, but it is well described even though it will take more than one reading to understand it completely.

Comment: Thank you very much for such straight answer. I supposed that my second assumption is correct (that every byte of the instruction will take  each 1 address) because in page 58 (Instructions in Program Memory) it does say that "program memory is addressed in bytes" and that "Instructions are stored as two bytes or four bytes in program memory".

Comment: @somename Yes that's correct. All memory is addressed as bytes, it's just that program memory only allows access to even numbered addresses because the LSB of PC is forced to zero. So a single-word instruction is two bytes and a two-word instruction is four bytes, as you said.